# Alternating Designs For Loop Results

Tags: php, loops

I am looking to create alternating designs for the content of each post returned in my loop. In short I want the first post to display left align, next right align, and so on. I have not been able to find a way to do this. Any ideas?

Comment: Need a lil' more info there pardner.  Programming language?  Is it perchance an ASP.NET web application?

Comment: Nope it's a PHP web application...more specifically Wordpress. I am trying to get the loop to display alternating css classes.

Comment: My code looks like this 

<div class='<%# (Container.ItemIndex % 2) == 0 ? "containerleft" : "containerright" %>'>
<?php the_content(); the_title('- '); ?>
</div>

Comment: Uh yes, my code will not work if it's PHP. I'll let someone else answer for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($posts as $post) {
    echo "<div class=\"" . (++$count % 2 ? 'left' : 'right') . "\">"
        . $post['postText'] // or whatever the crazy wordpress thing is
        . "</div>"
    ;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the results and then check if an incremented counter is even or odd and display left or right depending on that.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the modulo operator '%'

```
0 % 2 = 0
1 % 2 = 1
2 % 2 = 0
3 % 2 = 1
...
100 % 2 = 0
101 % 2 = 1
```

You can have a repeating pattern of as many as you like:

```
0 % 4 = 0
1 % 4 = 1
2 % 4 = 2
3 % 4 = 3
4 % 4 = 0
5 % 4 = 1
....
```

C.